# retrieve total number of items while using the LIMIT keyword

Tags: mysql, mariadb

What I'm trying to do is returning both my queried (and limited) results as well as the total number of items in the table. Here's what I have so far.

```
    SELECT id, name
    FROM ??
    WHERE
        user_id = ?
    LIMIT ? , ?;

    SELECT COUNT(*) as total
    FROM ??
    WHERE
        user_id = ?
    ;
```

This is two SQL queries and I was wondering how or if it's possible to combine it into one. I'd like the total to be by itself (if possible), otherwise as an attached column to each row. Or maybe what I have now is the most optimal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
    ...
    LIMIT ...

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

[*Reference.*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

Or, I would vote for the `CROSS JOIN`, not the subquery.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you *could* include the count in each row using a subquery:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable WHERE user_id = ?) total
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    user_id = ?;
```

But, from a separations of concerns point of view, this is probably not best practice.  Instead, more typically I would expect to see two separate queries here.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking about the best way to query my database. Maybe I will keep it as two statements. I will accept the answer when I can

Comment: Missing a comma.  And the subquery will be repeatedly performed.

Comment: @RickJames I would be surprised if the MySQL optimizer isn't smart enough to cache the result of the subquery.

Comment: OK.  If that were a "dependent subquery" (`inner.user_id = outer.user_id`) instead of hard coded constant, it would be repeatedly executed.

Comment: You're right...I should have used a cross join, which would guarantee that correlation cannot happen.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do the same using `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT 
        t1.id,
        t1.[name],
        t2.cnt 
FROM 
        yourtable t1

CROSS JOIN 
        (
            SELECT 
                    COUNT(1) AS cnt 
            FROM 
                    yourtable 
            WHERE 
                    [user_id] = ? 
        ) t2
WHERE 
        t1.[user_id] = ?
LIMIT 
        ?, ?
```

Comment: and if I need a limit on the first table?

Comment: you can use limit in the outer query after  the where clause